# How to rotate only origin?

Tags: origin

how to only origin rotate ? The object will remain in place. I want it in the picture example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no picture example. Please use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136545/edit) below your question to add a [correct link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to the image.

Comment: Please use the builtin tools for image upload in the toolbar, not external hosting sites

Comment: Ok I fixed pictures

Comment: You were not supposed to remove the question. Now this whole thread has become useless. Please [take the tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and read what Stackexchange is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need to do is rotate the mesh without changing the rotation of the origin, you can either rotate the object then apply the rotation as Josh said in his answer, and after that rotate the object again to the desired orientation of the origin, or rotate the mesh in edit mode, the origin will remain unchanged in this case, then in object mode do the last step.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the origin to rotate 90 degrees on X axis, in object mode press <kbd>R</kbd> followed by  <kbd>X</kbd> then -90 Enter,  then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Apply Rotation), then <kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>X</kbd> 90 Enter.
replace <kbd>X</kbd> with <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> depending on what axis you need, -90 is the degree of rotation replace that too with whatever value you need.